# Interfacing Matlab to a network socket

Tags: matlab, networking

I need to import data from a network socket straight into a Matlab environment for the Scientists on my team to process.

Can I use Java to implement the TCP protocol parsing from within Matlab? The idea is that if the application needs to outgrow Matlab, I would already have the network protocol parsing sorted out.

Comment: Yes, you can. There's a contribution on the MATLAB File Exchange called "pnet" that you could use for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call java classes and their methods directly from Matlab functions or command window

```
function sock = opensocket()
  sock = java.net.Socket(..)
  ....
```